# Nothing lasts forever, [so | nor] do we?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Like the title may already suggest, I am wondering if "so" or "nor" would be right in place for refering that something is (not) like stated in the main sentence. What do you think?

Comment: I'd say never, never use this construction. Whether you use *so* or *nor*, it remains not only incomprehensible but misleading to the average English reader.

Comment: Nothing lasts forever, and *neither* do we.

Comment: [I Am America (And So Can You!)](http://www.amazon.com/Am-America-So-Can-You/dp/0446580503)

Comment: @Peter Shor: Even *neither* seems a bit odd to me, since if *nothing lasts forever*, by implication *everything is ephemeral*. I don't think you can say "**Everything** has property X, **and so does** [something which by implication wasn't included in that preceding *everything*]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both alternatives are actually possible, depending on what you want to say. The sentence is ambiguous and therefore it's very difficult to tell what you're going after.

If you say:

> Nothing lasts forever and so do we.

You mean:

> Nothing lasts forever and we also last forever => We are immortal.

If you say:

> Nothing lasts forever and neither do we.

You mean:

> Nothing lasts forever and we don't last forever => We will die one day.

Comment: I just hope others are going to agree with me, because this is a very tough situation you've proposed. You should probably un-accept my answer and wait for others to up-vote or down-vote or propose their ideas.

Comment: @DavidWallace: well, this is a confusing situation and I don't mean to argue, because now I'm even more confused than ever. Do you think that "nothing does ..." should be followed by "nor do ..." to continue expressing the negativity?

Comment: Diamonds last forever and so do we?
Neither we nor anything else lasts forever

Comment: This ambiguity, and therefore, the argument will last forever. I'd never want to hazard a guess if a sentence implies something or its exact opposite.

Comment: No, this is wrong.  You can't use "so do we" after *nothing,* for either meaning.  I think what you want is "nothing lasts forever and neither do we."

Comment: @RiMMER Ψ: I admire your fortitude in trying to bend *"nothing"* into a "substantive noun" which can be considered to have the property of immortality, so I won't actually *downvote* the answer. But I do feel this is simply playing with words and ontological concepts that don't really make sense, so I'm not going to upvote either!

Comment: @PeterShor: fixed!

Comment: I've removed my earlier comment; it no longer applies now that you've changed the answer somewhat.  To be honest, I don't have a problem with "nor" in this sentence; but I don't think I speak the same dialect of English as Rimmer.

Comment: @RiMMER Ψ - Ok, I just do for now as you suggested. I did not think, that this would become a that quite interesting discussion.

To be honest, this question was keeping me busy for a whole while now.

Answer (score 2):

"Nothing lasts forever and so do we." would mean Nothing and we last forever which might make sense if the we here is immortal. Maybe if you had a god say it.

Reminds me of the joke: 
Villain: Nobody can stop me!
Loser guy turned hero: I am nobody.