# Which is correct..Nothing last forever? or Nothing lasts forever?

Tags: word-usage

Why is 'Nothing lasts forever' correct instead of 'Nothing last forever'?

Comment: The latter of the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can 'nothing' ever be preceded by a plural verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53723/can-nothing-ever-be-preceded-by-a-plural-verb)  (Also a little related: [Nothing lasts forever so|nor do we](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57900))

Answer (score 4):

**Nothing lasts forever**

Use "lasts" with a singular subject.

Comment: "Nothing" is considered singular.

Answer (score 1):

From the origin of nothing we can see that it's an indefinite pronoun, so the verb needs the *-s* as it uses the third person.